# Is this a bug in Enriched Mode?

Tags: enriched-mode

This is how to do it:

1- create a new empty file and open it
2- write abc
3- change its face to bold and its foreground color to blue
4- type enter to return to line
5- type `M-o d` to choose the default face
6- write def and type enter
You should get this:

[image]

7- but after saving the file, and reopening it, I get this:

[image]

As you can see, the second line becomes bold too. When I open the enriched text file in raw text mode, I find this:

```
Content-Type: text/enriched
Text-Width: 70

<bold><x-color><param>blue</param>abc

</x-color><x-bg-color><param>white</param><x-color><param>SystemWindowText</param>def

</x-color></x-bg-color></bold>
```

I tested this on Windows 10, but I get the same problem with Debian too. I also used the command `emacs -q` to ignore my **.emacs** file and start an *out-of-the-box* verion of emacs.

This is my `M-x emacs-verion` on Windows:
*GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2018-05-30*

Comment: Consider `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: I have discovered that packages like ([Elcord](https://github.com/Mstrodl/elcord)) can cause problems with Enriched Text Mode.